# handling unexpected bash command output

Tags: bash, error-handling, hp-ux

I am attempting to handle an unexpected output from a command within a for loop. I am using a proprietary unzip utility (**mfunzip**), however when the utility encounters a corrupt file, it begins to echo out an endless "Fatal error in InputBit!" message.

I am attempting to capture the output and continue the loop onto the next file.

```
for FILE in $(ls); do
   if [ -d "$FILE" ]; then
      ...
      ...
      # without command output, it runs indefinitely
      output=$(mfunzip $currentfile $extractdir)

      # it never reaches here
      echo $output
      if [[ $output = *Fatal* ]]; then
         continue  
      fi
   fi
done
```

however it's not seem to be working as it blocks at the **output=$(mfunzip ... )** ... I would assume it's outputting endlessly to **$output**. The other problem seems that the "Fatal error" may not appear immediately, but rather half-way through attempting to **mfunzip** the file.

Are there better ways of handling this type of output?

Comment: Not related to your problem but it is much safer to use * instead of $(ls).

Comment: Abhishek this is not the actual script from the server, I just quickly whipped up a mockup of the for procedure in "some" folder to show where the issue is. :)

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces your problem. Your mockup code is fine; the only problem it could have is that `mfunzip` never completes.

Answer (score 0):

To "handle an (unexpected or expected) output from a command", you should use : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect , which is specially designed for this kind of things.